# TTY says ? on ps -p command

Tags: unix, ps

I am running on a python script on Putty using & at the end of the command. When I checked ps -p processid, it showed some name under TTY. After some time internet got disconnected. After connecting back, I check the process status using ps -p processid but this time I found '?' under TTY. Does this mean my script broke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it only means that the TTY, which the script was started from, was closed in the meantime.

If you want to know more about the status, look into the STAT column:

> It shows the status of the process. S stands for sleeping: the process
>   is waiting for something to happen. Z stands for a zombied process. A
>   zombied processes is one whose parent has died, leaving the child
>   processes behind. This is not a good thing. D stands for a process
>   that has entered an uninterruptible sleep. Often, these processes
>   refuse to die even when passed a SIGKILL. You can read more about
>   SIGKILL later in the next section on kill . W stands for paging. A
>   dead process is marked with an X. A process marked T is traced, or
>   stopped. R means that the process is runable.

source: http://www.slackbook.org/html/process-control-ps.html

Comment: That means my script is still running and would produce results, right? Because I see TIME column getting incremented.

Comment: Correct. I updated my post with info about the STAT column. Also, you should be able to interact with the process with process control tools like `kill`. Unfortunately, you cannot foreground the process again, once the original shell was closed.

Comment: I have 'R' under STAT column. What does it mean when you say "Unfortunately, you cannot foreground the process again, once the original shell was closed."?

Comment: `R` means that the process is actively doing stuff, i.e. it's not a zombie, and it's not slepping either. I mentioned the “cannot foreground” thing in case you wondered if you could foreground the process with something like `fg`.

Comment: I see the script is still running because the resultant file size is incrementing. But when I check the process id using ps -p <process_id>, it is coming out to be blank. What does this indicate?

Comment: Hm, I don't know, could be several reasons. You could check with `ps ax | grep SCRIPT_NAME` if there's a process with your name. Otherwise, I'd suggest to start a new SO question, because it would be too complex to discuss in the comments.